# Maxima of increasing function multiplied by its symmetryc

Tags: maxima-minima

Let $f$ be a function with the following properties:

- $f$ is strictly increasing
- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(1) = 1$

What are the maxima of $g(x) = f(x)f(1 - x)$? More specifically:

- Under which conditions do we have that $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is the only maximum for $g$?
- Can there be some $f$ so that $g(\frac{1}{2})$ is **not** the **absolute maximum** of $g$?

Answer (score 0):

There exists a counterexample actually: take $f(1/2)=1/2, f(4/5)=99/100, f(1/5)=1/2-1/10000$ for example. You can construct even continuous and differentiable such functions so I am not sure on what conditions you have to impose on the function to get your desired result.

Comment: Am I missing something? How does $f(x - 1)$ relate to $f(1 - x)$? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry just a typo

Comment: This is just the AM-GM inequality or the inequality $(f(x)+f(1-x))^2\geq{0}$ in disguise.